# Postgresql, How to escape single quote in dynamic json when it was concatenated into string?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have function that triggers when table is being updated. Then it tries to send this data as json into remote database via dblink:

```
statement := 'INSERT INTO mytable(my_data) VALUES (''' || my_json || ''')';
PERFORM dblink('my connection data', statement);
```

`my_json`  is formed by `json_build_object` method with some dynamic data. When some of this json fields values contains single quote, this function starts throw syntax errors.

I know that I need to use double single quotes, but I can't because data is dynamic.

For example if my json is like this:

```
{ "a": "It's a test"  }
```

It throws:

Syntax error at s

Comment: I would use a foreign table for this, not db_link. That would give you a plain INSERT statement for this foreign table and you wouldn't have this issue. The function format() could be of help if want to keep db_link

Comment: @FrankHeikens tried to use format. Still throws syntax errors.

Comment: And these syntax errors are highly confidential?

Comment: @FrankHeikens it writes syntax error were neighboring to single quote letter

Comment: We don't have access to your computer, we can't see what you're doing. Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quote_literal()` to add the 2nd apostrophe:

```
with src(a) as (select '{ "a": "It''s a test"  }') 
select a, quote_literal(a) from src;
            a            |       quote_literal
-------------------------+----------------------------
 { "a": "It's a test"  } | '{ "a": "It''s a test"  }'
```

Comment: It worked partially. I have made like this `my_json := quote_literal(my_json)`.   It added second apostrophe, but now it added this weird `'E'`  which breaks the syntax at "{"

Comment: Well. It worked, but now it corrupts double quoted strings

Comment: ? what do you mean? Note that since the output is quoted, you don't have to re-quote it when building the query (either via concatenation or via the better `format()`)

Comment: It turns  `{"a": "Hello \"user\""}`  into  `{"a": "Hello \\"user\\""}`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
statement := format('INSERT INTO mytable(my_data) VALUES (%L)', myjson);
```

Based on your comments, I would point that:

- there must not be single quotes around `%L`.
- the fact that the contents represent a json value does not change anything to how it should be quoted. Any **literal** to **inject** into that statement would be treated the same.

Another way using `quote_literal()` and not using `format()` would be:

```
statement := 'INSERT INTO mytable(my_data) VALUES (' || quote_literal(myjson) || ')';
```

Again there are no single quotes to add around `quote_literal(myjson)`. It's the responsibility of `quote_literal` to add these quotes.

Comment: Now there is new problem. If my json string value has double quote it outputs it like this:    `{"a": "Hello \"user\" "}`  but this `%L` and `quote_literal` function breaks them and adds extra slash  `{"a": "Hello \\"user\\" "}`  which throws again syntax error

Comment: @Mr.D: `quote_literal('{"a": "Hello \"user\" "}')` produces `E'{"a": "Hello \\"user\\" "}'` which is a valid literal. You get a syntax error presumably because you're reinjecting that literal with inadequate code that is not shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer to my own question.

The way I was able to solve this problem I have added some fixes before forming my statement:

```
my_json := json_build_object(...);

my_json := REPLACE(payload, '''', '''''');
```

Only after that I have formed my statement for my dblink:

```
statement := 'INSERT INTO mytable(my_data) VALUES (''' || my_json || ''')';
PERFORM dblink('my connection data', statement);
```